# Toggle between two View Controllers without using UISegmentedControl (iOS)

Tags: ios, switch-statement, toggle, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I'm writing an iOS app, hoping that the user can toggle between view A and B, operate on either one, and screen elements retain their states (maps, lists, text) after toggle away.

I've been thinking of several options:

1. Use navigation controller, start with A, push B, pop B. This way, every time I have to re-set B's elements right?
2. Start with A, present B modally from A, same effect as option 1?
3. Use UISegmentedControl on one view controller for A and B. This will work, except the default segmented control is hard to customize to the look I need.

Do you have other suggestions that avoid the drawbacks of the above? Please correct me if my assumptions are not accurate too. Thanks!

Comment: You can use 3rd option and use a Custom UISegmentControl

Comment: Here are few examples : `BKSegmentedViewController` and `HMSegmentedControl`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but have you considered a UITabBarController? It sounds like this is exactly the functionality you need. You can hide the tab bar if you want to have a custom control for switching between the view controllers as well if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks looks like UITabBarController is the way to go. I'm learning how to customize it next. Thanks for the pointer!